# chromatic number when drawing edges between components in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is the following true? Let a graph consist of $k$ connected components , each being k-colorable. Now, if  for each pair of components, we draw $k-1$ edges between them, then the resulting graph is still k-colorable.   Is there any known theorem or literature about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is false even for $k=3$, with three copies of $K_3$ and two added edges between each pair:

[image]

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be the bottom vertex of each $K_3$. We add edges from $v_1$ (the bottom vertex of the top $K_3$) to each vertex of the other $K_3$'s *other* than $v_2$ and $v_3$. This forces $v_2$ and $v_3$ to have the same color as $v_1$ (no other vertex in those copies of $K_3$ can have that color). But then we add an edge between $K_2$ and $K_3$, and so the graph is no longer $4$-colorable.

(In fact, replacing the top $K_3$ by a single vertex, this graph becomes a [Moser spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle).)

The same construction works for $k>3$.

Comment: Thanks. What if say that every component can have at most k-1 edges in total to other components?

Comment: Then it's true. (More generally, when you connect two $k$-colorable graphs by $k-1$ edges, the result is $k$-colorable, because you can permute one coloring to avoid conflicts with the other.)

Comment: A simpler example for $k=3$: start with $3K_2$ and add edges so as to create a $K_4$.